# Catalog URL Rewrites not working for "Duplicated" products

Tags: product, url-rewrite

**Facing a strange issue:**
Whenever client "duplicates" a product from Admin, then the URL Rewrite of the new product doesn't get updated in the Rewrites table, even if client gives a different URL-Key everytime or doesn't give any URL-Key to newly duplicated products.

As a result the newly created products(with "Duplicate" button) have URLs redirecting to either 404 page or original products(from which they're cloned) or some other product randomly.

Can anyone guide me on this, as to what causes this issue & how to resolve?

Comment: First thing to check is if the MVC url works. This is the `catalog/product/view/id/xxx` url. If it does not, the root cause is not with rewrites, but the rewrites is a symptom.

Answer (score 1):

By default, duplicated products are set to disabled. You deliberately need to enable the product (regardless of the status of the product you cloned).

Comment: Client knows that only enabled products are visible & accessible on website, he enabled those cloned products, but still url-rewrite not working (404 or wrong url redirection).

Comment: Do they have an inventory and set to in stock? That is another one that usually catches people out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reindex catalog_url_rewrite.